# Receive video ID after posting to YouTube API via Ajax

Tags: xmlhttprequest, youtube-api, cors, plupload

My question is an extension of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340903/can-i-upload-to-youtube-without-a-full-page-refresh-using-formdata).

I am using JavaScript to post videos to the v2 YouTube API, via Plupload (HTML5 runtime). I am using OAuth2 to get authorized tokens and a CORS request to set the metadata. I am able to upload videos successfully, but the 302-coded response returned by YouTube gets lost. I am not able to retrieve the ID of the uploaded video, which would ordinarily be present as a GET parameter of the URL redirected to as part of the 302 response.

After uploading the video, how can I get the ID of the video?

It seems like `xhr.getResponseHeader(location)` would give it to me, but it is undefined with Plupload. Is this because Plupload is overriding the default XMLHttpRequest object and only exposing certain attributes? If I used vanilla XMLHttpRequest objects, would it work OK? Can the 302 be intercepted in all browsers?

Comment: Does this sample help? There is code that gets the video id, but it is in response to a 200, not a 302: http://gdata-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gdata/youtube_upload_cors.html

Comment: No, unfortunately. The response is 200 only after following the 302 and performing a whole-page redirect. (Note the use of `$('#upload-form').submit();`)